# How to set combined value to ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to assign ng-init value=d.id+d.concept_class  like ng-init="m_concept_class=**12 abc**"

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">

  <input type="text" ng-model="m_concept_class" 
        ng-init="m_concept_class={{d.id; d.concept_class}}" >    
</div>
```

When i use this syntax 
`ng-init="m_concept_class={{d.id}} {{d.concept_class}}"`
i can see data "12 abc" in browser's inspect element feature, but does not display in text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use interpolation, simply use concatenation.

*Use*

```
m_concept_class=d.id  + ' ' +d.concept_class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add it :-)

```
 <div ng-repeat="d in data">

  <input type="text" ng-model="m_concept_class" 
        ng-init="m_concept_class=d.id +d.concept_class" />    
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daaypk2g/)

Answer (score 0):

Set value to input element while initializing it use [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) instead of `ng-init`

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
  <input type="text" ng-model="m_concept_class" ng-value="m_concept_class=d.id +' '+ d.concept_class" >    
</div>
```

Either you can also use `ng-init`, but ng-value would be more preferable, its like `value` attribute of html which will set value for input element and bind to the ng-model variable.

**NOTE**

> Don't use `{{}}` interpolation directive inside `ng-value` or `ng-init` as they only
>   support expressions.